# jQuery div class under div  select radio button value

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <input name="aa" value="aa" type="radio"/>
        <input name="aa" value="bb" type="radio"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the select radio value in jQuery.

I am using this $('.outer.inner input[type="radio"]:checked')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.outer .inner input:radio:checked');
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgANq/)**

The issue in your selector is `.outer.inner`. This will look for both the classes on the same element. May be you missed the sapce between the 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put a class to the input

```
<input class="myradio" name="aa" value="aa" type=radio/>
```

And use

```
$('.myradio').change(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());}
);
```

But if you create them by code you want to use

```
 $('.myradio').live('change', function(){
      console.log($(this).val());}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever have one set of radio buttons with the same name in a form, therefore you can access the selected radio button value by the name you have given the set of radio buttons. ie.

```
var result = $('input:radio[name=aa]:checked').val());
```

... or if you want the result when you change, you can use the following, again, referencing the name given to your set of radio buttons.

```
$('input:radio[name=aa]').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EMGmY/)